# Save appointments to my default calendar in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I was hoping that with the new calendar API of wp8.1, I am now able to fully replace the native calendar app with my own.

But after a few hours of searching in the API documentation, I came to the point that this is still NOT possible.

This is what i concluded so far:

1. I can create my own `AppointmentCalendar` with full read and write access. But this calendar won't sync to my other devices.
2. I can add/remove/edit appointments in all other Calendars, but just over the native UI with the `AppointmentManager`. This still takes some time to open the native calendar app and the user has to manually press the save button.
3. There is still the old way. I need to dive into the Outlook.com/Google Calendar/... APIs, to save appointments straight out of my own calendar app.

Is there a way to set my default calendar (Outlook.com) from Readonly (ReadWrite=Systemonly) to ReadandWrite(ReadWrite =full)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform `AppointmentCalendar` API doesn't allow for writing directly to a online calendar provider.

To implement write-support, you would need to implement a custom provider for each calendar, for example Outlook.com and GMail.com each have individual APIs, although IMAP often can be used as a default protocol. Each requires individual authentication.

For Outlook.com you would need to utilize OAuth, ideally via. Single Sign-On, and then use the [IMAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/live/hh826535.aspx) to integrate your application with the Outlook.com calendar.

So in short, there is no way for 3rd party developers to fully replace the default calendar application on Windows Phone when it comes to writing appointments. All you can do is to write a different visual front for the built-in calendar.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Maybe I will give it a try with the Hotmail API. BTW your "IMAP API" link is broken.

Comment: @Claus Jorgensen: Can you share the code how to use the save appointment task for Windows Phone 8.1